# MonoDroid: Not connecting to Emulator

Tags: monodevelop, xamarin.android

Using MonoDevelop, MonoDroid on a Mac 4.0.6

I am attempting running the sample project SearchableDictionary. When I press Debug, the "Select a Device" dialog appears to choose the emulator. Even though the emulator is running, it is not recognized. Each time we run the debug, it tries to run a new instance of the emulator and never installs the app there.

Is there a way to get MonoDroid to attach to a running Emulator, one that it created in the install process?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the Android debugging bridge to refresh in general - not just for MonoDroid - try opening a command line (shell) and using:

```
adb kill-server

adb start-server
```

This is often required (in my experience)!

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html for more adb info (Android Debug Bridge)